# Firebase database realtime are ignoring some values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have an android app and firebase realtime database.
I have a class called `Game` which have properties described below.
Recently i've decided added a new property called `likes` but when I read the snapshot all fields were read except the new field `likes`

Why this behavior?

[image]

```
data class Game (
    val id: String? = null,
    val title: String? = null,
    val release_date: String? = null,
    val gender: String? = null,
    val image: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val rating: Long? = null,
    var likes: Long? = null,
    var liked: Boolean? = null,
    val video: String? = null,
    val plataformas: String? = null
)

private val gamesVEL : ValueEventListener by lazy {
    object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("firebase","jejejejje")
            juegos.clear()
            dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                val game = it.getValue(Game::class.java)
                juegos.add(game!!)
            }
            queryStars.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(starsVEL)

        }

    }
}
```

## UPDATE

A install in new device solve the problem but not in older devices. I mean if i've the installed app before the field `likes` is still missed.

Comment: could you show the code where you read ?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake done

Answer (score 1):

> I read the snapshot all fields were read except the new field likes

This is **only** happening when you are using the app on devices that have older versions of your app.

> Why this behavior?

This is happening because the earlier versions of your app do not inculde the updated version of your `Game` class which contains that new added `likes` field. With other words, the older version can only read and write properties that are aware of.

To solve this, you should update the older version to the new veriosn so it can see the new added property.

Comment: I've updated the versionCode and versionName of the gradle file but the results are the same,  `likes` field is still missing.

Comment: You should **not** update only the versionCode and versionName of the gradle file because it wll not solve your problem, you should update the entire app. All devices should have the latest version of your app, which includes your modified `Game` class in which this new property exists. Have you tried this out?

Comment: I'm running the updated code in two devices. One is a new install and everything works fine, but the second have same code as the first one but the field `likes` is still missing.

Comment: Yes, that the correct behaviour. Without updating the app to the latest version **also** on the second device, the problem will persist. So to solve this, as I already mentoned, update the app to the lastest version on the second device and your problem will be solved. That's it!

Comment: when i say the first device have the same code as the second one i think its obvious that I mean the second device is updated to the last code version.

Comment: If you have the same latest version on both devices, are you sure that each one of them is quering the database and get documents that have that new `likes` property?

Comment: yes I'm sure. I know it's weird. Thanks for the support anyway.

Comment: I was asking you the last question because I see in your screenshot that **not** all your objects have that `likes` property. In particular, the second object (`1 ... 5`), does **not**, right?

Comment: @AlexMalmo yes you are right. But that shouldn't produce this behavior.

Comment: Yes it should since that data does not exist. This is the right behavior, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183751/discussion-between-ricardo-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: As I aslo see in your screenshot, you're right, that likes property is missing. The reason why you cannot get its value is NOT because of your updated app is because it actually it does not exist. The reason why that property does not exist is because you didn't add it. Is not enough to add that property ONLY it in your POJO class, you actually need to populat the property in database in order to see it, right? Add that value in the database and tell me if it works, ok?

Comment: So you mean is i have to set likes value in all items of blog?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In order to be able to read some data, that data should exist in the first place. So please update that data and tell me if it works.

Comment: That's not accurate since i have one device which is receiving that field.

Comment: If one device is able to read data, it means that particular data **exists**. If that data does **not** exist it cannot be read. You cannot read something that it does **not** exist. So for sure, you are reading data from an object in which that `likes` property exists, right? If you'll update that property allover your database, there will be no problems anymore. Have you tried this?

Comment: You are reading data from an object in which that likes property exists, right? Yes.

Comment: If you'll update that property allover your database, there will be no problems anymore. Have you tried this? No. Because i think is a workarround. I can't find oficial doc that say a new field should be allover collection is required.

Comment: You think it's a workaround but it's not. This how things work. In order to be able to read some data, that particular data must exist. If you just define a new property in your POJO class doesn't mean that you have some data in database. You should add it in order to get it back. Is the same as you say, I want to get a value from a variable which doesn't exist and this not possible, right?

Comment: A field should exist and should hold some data in order to be able to get it back, otherwise you'll get that error. Which makes sense.

Comment: I finally decide to try uninstall and install again the app in the device which I'm having problems without modify firebase database and now is working fine. But I think this is not a proper behavior.